# how does surviving configuration changes mechanisms work?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I have three similar questions about surviving configuration changes. I know three ways to retain objects across configuration changes but I don't know how they work under the hood.

1. Overriding `onSaveInstanceState`. I know it puts the data in the bundle. but how does it survive configuration changes? what really bundle is? does it belong to activity? do we have only one bundle in the app? (I know we can make different instances but when we put our data with `putExtra` or `onSaveInstanceState` or any other method, are they going to the same place?)
2. Using `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`. this is used to retain `viewModelStore` across configuration changes. so how it works and where does it put the data?(I know about deprication)
3. Retained(Holder) Fragment and `setRatinInstance()` method in the fragment. the same question(I think the activity just uses the `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` for this, correct me if I'm wrong)

I searched the net and StackOverflow for this but I couldn't find anything. I also tried to go through the actual codes, but no luck!
since the questions are relevant I thought I put them all in one question. hope it's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Overriding onSaveInstanceState. I know it puts the data in the bundle. but how does it survive configuration changes? what really bundle is? does it belong to activity? do we have only one bundle in the app? (I know we can make different instances but when we put our data with putExtra or onSaveInstanceState or any other method, are they going to the same place?)

That's not really "retention across config change", that's more-so "saving at process-level durability" which is then re-used for config changes. The reason why I wouldn't consider it "retention" is because the object is parcelled as Parcelable, then a copy is created on restoration.

Anyway, [the ActivityRecord has a bundle](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityRecord.java#118), each task stack has its own ActivityRecords, and the task stack is saved and restored by the system when process death happens. This mechanism just happens to "also handle config change".

`Intent.putExtra` works very similarly, yes.

> Using onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() and getLastNonConfigurationInstance(). this is used to retain viewModelStore across configuration changes. so how it works and where does it put the data?(I know about deprication)

Unlike `onSaveInstanceState`, this actually is an OS-level callback that only serves to retain an object across config changes. There used to be `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance`/`getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance`, but it was deprecated in favor of ViewModel, as ViewModel is intended to be the "one and only standard" way of retaining across config change. Internally, it's just `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` of the `viewModelStore` (which is a map), though.

> Retained(Holder) Fragment and setRetainInstance() method in the fragment. the same question(I think the activity just uses the onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() for this, correct me if I'm wrong)

Yes, although unfortunately that is also deprecated in the latest Jetpack Fragments versions (in order to simplify the interaction of fragments and their lifecycle). The fragment manager is retained as non-config, and the retained fragments are retained along with it, using `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` of the `FragmentActivity` (I think now it's called `FragmentManagerViewModel`).

Non-configuration instances are kept in [the ActivityClientRecord](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#500) which are not persisted by the [ActivityStack](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityStack.java#831).

Hope that covers enough.